# Not Able to Exclude a Folder in WinMerge

Tags: winmerge

I'm using WinMerge and want to exclude any folder, and associated sub-folders, called 'help'. For example, I have a folder called 'help' and want to exclude that folder and all it's sub-folders. I tried using the following filter:

```
name: Archibus Conv
desc: Archibus Conversion
def: include
d: \\\.svn$ ## Subversion working copy
d: \\_svn$  ## Subversion working copy ASP.NET Hack
d: \\\help$ ## Help system
d: \\^help ## Help system
```

But I am still picking up most, if not all, the 'help' subsystem files. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

The problem had to do with my regular expression. The following did the trick:

D: \help\  ## help system